# cout-ing symbol after every n times?

Tags: c++

I want to combine the symbol "." with the result and add it after every 8 (characters or numbers) 
i tried to use for loop but i couldn't ,here's my code it's a kind of sum that subtract the smaller number from the bigger number and cout the symbol of the bigger number which is "A" at the first process and keep subtracting smaller from bigger till the end.
what i want is cout-ing "." before "A" and after every 8 processes:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int A=26;
    int B=7;
    cout<<endl;
    while(A!=B)
    {
        if(A>B)
        {
            A=A-B;
            if(A==B){cout<<"AB";}
            else cout<<"A";
        }
        else
        {
            B=B-A;
            if(A==B){cout<<"BA";}
            else cout<<"B";
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sounds like you should utilize the `modulus %` operand.

Comment: @bwtrent Show me your point please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a `int count` variable. Increment `++count` at every process, and print whatever you want when `count` becomes 8.

Something like this:

```
int main()
{
    int A=26;
    int B=7;
    char bigger='.'; //I suppose this is what you want to print periodically!
    int count = 0;
    cout << bigger;
    while(A!=B)
    {
        if(A>B)
        {
            A=A-B;
            if(A==B) { cout << "AB"; count += 2;}
            else { cout << "A"; ++count; }
        }
        else
        {
            B=B-A;
            if(A==B) { cout << "BA"; count += 2; }
            else { cout << "B"; ++count; }
        }
        if(count == 8)
        {
            cout << bigger;
            count = 0; //reset it back to 0
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sample example please

Comment: Can you please be specific as to what you want? I tried my best to help you! I still want to. @user3516293

Comment: The answer in my example will be : AAABAABA
I want it to be  .AAABAABA.  , and the '.' repeat every 8 characters

Comment: @user3516293 check now!

Comment: I have purposefully left a glitch in the program in a special use case, and given the hint, I expect it to solve it yourself! You can always come back if you face any problem!